# Start SQL job if not already running

Tags: sql

I use SQL Server 2014.
In my stored procedure, I need check if a SQL job is alreay running or not. If not then I need to start it.
I use below SQL to achieve it. And it's not working well all the time. Sometimes it does not start the job even if it's not started already.

Can you please share with me some simple and neat way to achieve this? Thanks.

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(     
    SELECT *
    FROM 
        msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view A
        INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity B ON A.job_id = B.job_id 
    WHERE  
        B.run_Requested_date IS NOT NULL  
        AND B.stop_execution_date IS NULL  
        AND A.name = 'MyJob'
) 
BEGIN      
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'MyJob';
END
```

Comment: Can you share logs or output or dumps?

Comment: Also, what does the job do that you need to do?  This seems like a poor design on the surface.